# Retrieve and Use OAuth 2.0 Credentials newbie guide

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

This would be a silly question and some will downvote this surely. But Im a visual and hands on learner.  Thats why i rely on example rather than documentation. And [THIS](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials)
code in google drive sdk documentation. I cant figure out which part should i put in

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // This is the initiatation process

    }
```

Google gave an example. But i cant run it. And i dont know asp.net yet.I realy dont know which part should I put. So can someone tell me? Just the part to be able to initiate the code. Maybe i can figure out what can i do to other function if i can only run it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I should not have to go to a second site to figure out what your talking part. Put the code your asking about in your question.

Comment: To answer your specific question you have to put a call to each method. I won't bother posting an answer since this question is likely to be closed since you have not done enough research. The example you linked to is C# so unless your also new to programming in C# you should be able to figure it out. Otherwise I suggest finding a different example since that is just an example class and is not enough to implement a Google Drive client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of hot to use this [Example Drive App: DrEdit for .NET](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet). If it is not working, please provide some debugging output, or errors.